Reactivity of 3-oxo-tetrahydrothiophene
I had some doubts about the reactivity of this molecule, or similar compounds, in which between the carbonyl group and the electronegative heteroatom there is a methylene group. As in this case:

I wonder if when forming an enolate, which hydrogens are more acidic. I understand that the one in the middle of the carbonyl and sulfur is that correct?
Since sulfur is a large atom with good polarizability I understand that it could bear some electronic charge better than if it were an oxygen.
Are there any reactions involving these types of compounds, I would like to be able to do some more research on the reactivity of these compounds, but I don't know how to look for this feature or similar reactions.

Reference 1 describes a condensation reaction with a 2-pyrone substrate and nonaqueous potassium hydroxide, eliminating a carbonate ion (charge-balanced by spectator potassium ions). The presence of the unaltered dimethylene moiety in the five-membered ring on the product indicates that the deprotonation site is at C-2 of the five-atom ring.

Reference

S. Rajappa, A.R. Deshmukh,
"3.10 - Thiophenes and their Benzo Derivatives: Reactivity".
Editor(s): Alan R. Katritzky, Christopher A. Ramsden, Eric F.V. Scriven, Richard J.K. Taylor,
Comprehensive Heterocyclic Chemistry III, Elsevier, 2008, Pages 741-841,
ISBN 9780080449920,
https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-008044992-0.00310-2.

